# how to overwrite nested default values in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have some nested default variables in my /defaults/main.yml:

```
php_fpm_pools:
  - name: www
    user: php-fpm
```

In the playbook, I want to overwrite the user default value, and I tried the following options, to no avail:

```
roles:
  - {
    name: php-fpm,

    php_fpm_pools.[www].user: vagrant
    php_fpm_pools.www.user: vagrant
    php_fpm_pools.['www'].user: vagrant
  }
```

What is the correct syntax that I have to use in order to overwrite that default value?

Answer (score 3):

There's no *easy* way to overwrite part of default dict/list.

You either overwrite full var, like:

```
roles:
  - role: php-fpm
    php_fpm_pools:
      - name: www
        user: vagrant
```

Or write your custom logic at the beginning of the role to merge your parameters with default variables.

Sometime there's an easy workaround like this:

```
def_pool_user: php-fpm
php_fpm_pools:
  - name: www
    user: "{{ def_pool_user }}"
```

This way you may override only `def_pool_user`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ansible here surprises me negatively, as this beats the purpose of having the default values - if I have to resend the whole set of 50 values from the playbook. In your second suggestion the def_pool_user will have to be def_pool_www_user and I will duplicate the work in the defaults file.

Comment: Default variables are totally fine in Ansible. You just need to reorganize them a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Filters | Combining hashes/dictionaries](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries)?

```
roles:
  - name: php-fpm
    php_fpm_pools: '{{ php_fpm_pools |combine({'user':'vagrant'}) }}'
```